# Not able to GET Image from Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django Rest Framework & facing some issue.

I have a small Task App API.

I'm able to save an image on the server but not able to get Image from API image hyperlink.

My Model.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    task_desc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/', default = 'pic_folder/None/no-img.jpg')
```

Views.py

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(
            max_length = None, use_url=True
        )   
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id','task_name','image')
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

APP Structure:-

```
TaskAPI  (Base Dir)
    TaskAPP
     media
```

I can Make a Request For POST successfully & It show correct image link but when i click on image link it gives error.

[image]

Error:- [image]
Please suggest how to get Image from link.

Comment: error? post the traceback.

Comment: I think the GET is working fine since you are getting image's URL. Maybe the problem is in the form? Can you show the HMTL code??

Comment: I agree. but is this link show me an image in the browser ? 
like any other server-side image link behave in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not included the `media url` in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-media-files-during-development) on serving media and static files.