# Can't display image on browser with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've a problem similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890814/not-able-to-get-image-from-django-rest-api), but none of its answers helped me to solve my issue.

Here we are : I'm able to save an image on the server but not able to get Image from API image hyperlink.

My files :

model.py

```
class Summary(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover_image/', max_length=255)
    userProfileSummary = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through='UserProfileSummary')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

views.py

```
class Summary(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover_image/', max_length=255)
    userProfileSummary = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through='UserProfileSummary')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

serializer.py

```
class SummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for summary item"""
    cover_image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Summary
        exclude = ('userProfileSummary',)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/static',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('Hello-viewset', views.HelloViewSet, base_name='hello-viewset')

urlpatterns= [
    path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_view()),
    path('UserProfileSummary/<int:id>/', views.UserProfileSummaryViewSet.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App structure :

```
- myproject/
 - cover_image/
 - media/
 - myproject_api/
  - models.py
  - serializers.py
  - ...
  - myproject/
   - settings.py
   - ...
```

And also, my main urls.py file (myproject/urls.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('myproject_api.urls'))
]
```

I can Make a Request For POST successfully & It show correct image link but when i click on image link it gives error.

[image]

What's wrong ?

Please help !

Comment: have you tried adding below line in your main project urls ..   url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),  .. I think you have added it in your app urls not in in the root urls. And in your  production environment you need configure the web server for serving static files.

Comment: I've added but it still doesn't work. I've also edited my code to add the structure of my the main urls.py file in case of...

Comment: add it in the main urls .. urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('myproject_api.urls')), url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,})
]

Comment: Got this error : `NameError: name 'url' is not defined`

Comment: Got this another error :( : `TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

Comment: looks like you are using django 1.10+  .. from django.views.static import serve .. url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),

Comment: I"ve Django 3.5

Comment: Thank you a lot @SajiXavier,it works great now

Comment: i have added the same as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you have added static media url in your app/urls. Move the same to your project/urls

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('myproject_api.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,})
]
```